# Plotly.js "bleeding" bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, svg, plotly

I have a stacked bar chart in Plotly.js (latest build) and upon hovering, the graph seems to leave a graphical trail:

[image: Bleeding hover effect]

I'm not sure how to solve this as it just uses the default hover effect ... Any help would be much appreciated, if I have left out some crucial information in order to describe the problem, I'd love to hear it as well.

Comment: It'd be nice if you can include code for us to be able to reproduce the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'll look into providing a jsfiddle, but I'll need some time